# Quantum ESPRESSO won't work in ASE

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, python, atomic-simulation-environment

I am trying to use Quantum ESPRESSO in ASE, but I keep getting the following error. When I run `pw.x` directly from the terminal, it works, so Quantum ESPRESSO appears to be installed correctly and it's path is seen. I have no idea how to deal with this.

Here is the complete error stack trace:

```
File "/home/doug/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/optimize/lbfgs.py", line 65, in __init__
Optimizer.__init__(self, atoms, restart, logfile, trajectory, master,

File "/home/doug/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/optimize/optimize.py", line 234, in __init__
self.set_force_consistent()

File "/home/doug/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/optimize/optimize.py", line 325, in set_force_consistent
self.atoms.get_potential_energy(force_consistent=True)

File "/home/doug/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/constraints.py", line 2420, in get_potential_energy
atoms_energy = self.atoms.get_potential_energy(

File "/home/doug/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/atoms.py", line 728, in get_potential_energy
energy = self._calc.get_potential_energy(

File "/home/doug/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/calculators/calculator.py", line 709, in get_potential_energy
energy = self.get_property('energy', atoms)

 File "/home/doug/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/calculators/calculator.py", line 737, in get_property
self.calculate(atoms, [name], system_changes)

File "/home/doug/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/calculators/calculator.py", line 938, in calculate
raise CalculationFailed(msg) ase.calculators.calculator.CalculationFailed: Calculator "espresso" failed with command "pw.x -in espresso.pwi failed in /home/doug/Documents/qetest with error code 127
```

Comment: https://databases.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/calculators/espresso.html Can you please confirm if you set up the path to the pw.x executable as described in the attached link? Because if you can run pw.x from terminal, and not from ASE, the error is almost certainly in how you call the executable from python.

Comment: @user9725 Could you please add a minimum reproducible code of your python code that gives this error?

Comment: setup your calculator as:      "export ASE_ESPRESSO_COMMAND="/path/to/pw.x -in PREFIX.pwi > PREFIX.pwo"